# Router RIPv2 displaying subnets not directly connected

Tags: cisco, router, packet-tracer, rip

Is there a way to show subnets on "Show IP route" that aren't directly connected, but are a hop or 2 away? Is this with Router RIPv2 "redistribute" or is there another way?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to display the routes a router knows? Or do you need to propagate routes between routers?

Comment: I need to show the routes that arent directly connected, but are connected to another router that the first router is connected. E.g. Router_A (cable) Router B (cable) subnet, i need to show Router B connection to subnet on router A's routing table.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The command is

```
show ip route rip
```

This will give you all the routes learned by RIP, which excludes directly connected ones.